# When I pass res.render object then in .ejs file it is undefined

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I want to show values of post object in my profilearea.ejs file.But when it renders to profilearea.ejs then it gives an error that "post is not defined".

Here is the code in node.js

```
PersonalInfo.findOne({username:req.body.name}, function(err,post){
    if(err || !post)
    {
        console.log("find is not done");
    }

    else
        res.render('profilearea.ejs', {post:post});

  }

})
```

This is the code in profilearea.ejs file

```
<section id="notification" data-role="page" >
       <header data-role="header" data-theme="b"><h2>INFORMATION</h2></header>
       <div data-role="content">

        <p> <%= post%> </p>
       </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: this looks correct to me. what does console.log(post) give you just before res.render()?

Comment: this gives me a complete object with all the values .This work fine

Comment: if you remove <%= post %> does the page work?

Comment: { _id: 50756baae35633f40e000001,
  name: 'amina',
  acronym: 'saf',
  province: '',
  district: '',
  tehsil: '',
  telephone_number: 'sfdsdsdfdsffsfd',
  demographics: '',
  username: 'amna',
  password: '123',
  __v: 0 }

Comment: yup the page works. Instead of this <p><%=post></p> i write <p>ana</p> this works

Comment: try adding a space `<%= post %>`

Answer (score 2):

I think part of the issue may be in not stringifying the object prior to rendering.

Try:

```
  else {
  var jpost = JSON.stringify(post);
  res.render('profilearea.ejs', {post:jpost});
  }
```