# object in ejs acts strangely

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have the `userdata` object in my page using `render('page',{userdata: data})`.

Where `userdata` is an object with properties:

```
{
usename: "jim",
latLng: {lat: 10, lng: -8},
address: {
  line1: "10 Main Street"
  line2: "London"
  country: "Great Britan"
  },
about: "I am jim"
}
```

In my `page.ejs` file I have the following two lines of code as a test.

```
<% console.log("My User data: " + userdata) %> 
<% console.log("The latLng field: " + userdata.latLng) %>
```

The first displays to the console:

```
My user data: {usename: 'jim',
latLng: {lat: 10, lng: -8},
address: {
  line1: "10 Main Street"
  line2: "London"
  country: "Great Britan"
  },
about: 'I am jim'}
```

but the second line displays:

```
The latLng field: undefined
```

Does anyone know what is happening? Is it because they are numbers not strings?? Is latLng a reserved variable name?? I am clueless as to why this is happening.

What I've tried:

saving lat and lng as strings. (no effect)

Some further info:

`typeof userdata` returns `object` in the rendering process.

`typeof data` before rendering also returns `object`.

Comment: Are you sure `data` in `render('page',{userdata: data})` is an object and not a String?

Comment: yes `data` is an object. And I know that this object is passed on as a local for rendering as can be seen in the output of the first `console.log()` statement.

Comment: Just for the sake of it you might want to print a `typeof data`, to completely take that out from the equation. There could be something in the middle changing it, it's not that I don't trust you, I just have little information :D

Comment: `typeof data` also returns `object`

Comment: Thanks for trying that out :) while looking around I've found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908967/when-i-pass-res-render-object-then-in-ejs-file-it-is-undefined is it of any help to you?